# Using DHCP libraries results infinite loop

Tags: c, linux, dhcp

I have a code that uses DHCP libararies(package : 4.2.6) to get the hardware address of the DHCP client connected to the system. During this process after DHCP objects got initialized, i tried dhcp_connect() as follows which results into an infinte loop.

```
dhcpctl_initialize ();
status=dhcpctl_connect (&connection, "127.0.0.1", 7911, 0);
```

When i tried to debug the issue, i found a function "omapi_wait_for_completion"(in ompai/dispatch.c), has a do-while check for waiter object and its status, the object should change its state to ready to come out of the this loop, but this is never happened which results into an infinite loop.

Here i am just copying the loop as a reference.

```
do {
    status = omapi_one_dispatch ((omapi_object_t *)waiter, t);
    if (status != ISC_R_SUCCESS)
      return status;
   } while (!waiter || !waiter -> ready);
```

NOTE:

- There is no issue when i run the binary generated from the code in system command line, but when i trigger the same command through an application we have this issue.
- The application that triggers my binary doesn't uses DHCP libraries or files.
- Please note that same binary with the same application is working
  fine with older DHCP package (3.0.5).

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You are playing with loopback and not the real interface. Run you program and check for which interface you set the address.

Comment: It is given that(in omapi/ompai.3 of dhcp package) to query the server running on the localhost for the details of the lease for IP address and also for some other information.
Since same binary is triggered by same application with older dhcp package is working fine, i suspect the new dhcp package. Because of this issue system gets hanged and goes for reboot.